# Allocating an Unknown Inherited Class from another Dynamic Library

Tags: c++, oop, dll, game-engine, game-development

I'm working on a small game engine project and I want to make an entity allocationg system.

The idea is this: Engine DLL is "unchangeable", provided by me.
Developers will be able to compile Game DLL themselves with custom entity types.

Every Entity is derived from `CBase` class of the Engine. Entities have class names, which will be used when reading the map. Entities will be "spawned" using those class names. It's basically an alias for that entity.

But there's a problem:

Allocation of "spawned" entites should be done in the engine. Engine should be able to call fundamental functions, and will not be able to call additional functions.

But Engine doesn't import these classes from the Game DLL, so I cant just use `new EntityClass`

How can I allocate unknown classes (derived from a known class) from the other DLL? Is there a way to "pass a type" through functions?

---

My workaround before was like this pseudocode:

> Engine:
>
> ```cpp
> class DLLEXPORT CBase
> {
>   std::string className;
>
>   virtual void Init();
>   virtual void OtherMethod();
> }
>
> CBase* CreateNewEntity(const char* classname)
> {
>   CBase* newentity = static_cast<CBase*>(SERVER_DLL_GETNEWOBJECT(classname));
>   newentity->Init();
>   entitylist.addentity(newentity);
> }
> ```
>
> Game DLL:
>
> ```cpp
> class DLLEXPORT CBaseEntity : public DLLIMPORT CBase
> {
>   //Called by engine
>   virtual void Init() override;
>   virtual void OtherFunction() override;
>
>   //Inaccesible by engine
>   virtual void AnotherFunction() override;
> }
>
> CBaseEntity* SERVER_DLL_GETNEWOBJECT(const char* classname)
> {
>   if (strcmp(className, "Entity_Weapon_Test") == 0)
>   {
>       return static_cast<CBaseEntity*>(new CTestWeapon);
>   }
>   else
>       return nullptr;
> }
> ```

SERVER_DLL_GETNEWOBJECT is exported from Game DLL, and imported into the Server DLL. It was going to be a predefined function.

But in this workaround, the allocation is done by the Game DLL, not by the engine. So I can't use it.

Comment: A factory function exported from the plugin is in fact the usual approach for this kind of arrangement. What again is wrong with it?

Comment: Why should it be the responsibility of the engine code to allocate? The user might want to change how memory is allocated as well (e.g. with something else than `new`/`delete`), so it should be up to them to provide an allocator either way.

Comment: Also, `SERVER_DLL_GETNEWOBJECT` should probably return a `std::unique_ptr<CBaseEntity>` or something similar, so that the engine doesn't need to explicitly call `delete` (which also might be accidentally mismatched with the wrong allocator if the game DLL doesn't use `new`).

Comment: @user17732522 The main thing is that this is mainly a toy project to learn new ways of doing things. I basically want to isolate the main memory management from the Game DLL as much as possible. Game DLL would act more like a "Scripting base". Of course, if you are an advanced user, you can modify the Engine DLL.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Mainly, I want to isolate memory management from the Game DLL as much as possible.

Comment: The server DLL doesn't even know how large an instance of `CTestWeapon` is. How can it possibly allocate a sufficiently large block of memory to hold that instance? Then, for all you know, `CTestWeapon`'s constructor needs to allocate more memory for whatever data structures it wants to maintain. Is it not allowed to itself call `new`, or have say a `std::vector<Something>` as a data member?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect something along these lines :

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

// Declare an "interface" (abstract baseclass)
// this is the only knowledge your engine
// and client code will share
//
// But make sure client code compiles with an ABI
// compatible compiler!
//
class EntityItf
{
public:
    virtual ~EntityItf() = default;
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
};

using creation_function_t = std::function<std::unique_ptr<EntityItf>()>;

class /*dllexport */ EntityFactory
{
public:
    // Meyers singleton
    inline static EntityFactory& Instance()
    {
        static EntityFactory factory;
        return factory;
    }

    void RegisterCreationMethod(const std::string& entity_name, creation_function_t creation_function)
    {
        if ( m_factory_functions.find(entity_name) != m_factory_functions.end())
        {
            throw std::runtime_error{"An entity with that name has already been registered"};
        }

        m_factory_functions[entity_name] = creation_function;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<EntityItf> CreateEntity(const std::string& entity_name)
    {
        if ( m_factory_functions.find(entity_name) == m_factory_functions.end())
        {
            throw std::runtime_error{"Unknown entity name"};
        }

        return m_factory_functions[entity_name]();
    }

private:
    EntityFactory() = default;
    ~EntityFactory() = default;

    std::map<std::string,creation_function_t> m_factory_functions;
};

// Developer code

class MyEntity :
    public EntityItf
{
public:
    void DoSomething() override
    {
        std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto& factory = EntityFactory::Instance();
    factory.RegisterCreationMethod("MyEntity", []{ return std::make_unique<MyEntity>(); });

    auto my_entity = factory.CreateEntity("MyEntity");
    my_entity->DoSomething();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think I get the general idea now. Thanks!